# I'm new in programming with C#

Tags: c#

How can I start with C#

Comment: Hmmm... let me think. Program something?

Comment: @Johannes For now, yes. But in theory, C# can target any runtime, depends on the compiler.

Comment: How much programming experience do you have?

Comment: Go-go-gadget vote-to-close-as-not-a-real-question

Answer (score 7):

First, get a copy of [Visual C# Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/), it's free.

Then, you could follow an online tutorial (use google), it could for instance be [the one found here](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive402.html). I would also recommend you get a good book.

If you are a total novice at programming, I would go for a book that teaches *programming* rather than C# specifically. Many C# books will assume you have at least some experience with programming.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has an excellent guide to [Getting Started With C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vcsharp/dd919145.aspx) on their web site. Download Visual C# 2008 Express and follow their instructions to create your first application.

If you're already comfortable with another object-oriented programming language, you might prefer to buy a decent book that takes you through the language from the perspective of an already experienced programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Borland (developers probably most famous for Delphi) have a free IDE to get started with building your c# applications. To learn more about c# builder please visit there website at http://www.borland.com/csharpbuilder/

SharpDevelop has a very intriguing Visual Studio look a like, developed in c# and offering it's source for both review and modification. Released under the GPL it is without a doubt a powerful c# IDE. To learn more about this IDE, please visit http://sharpdevelop.com/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx

If you need a good book, I would recommend Visual c# .NET 2003 in 24 Hours by Sams Publishing. I don't personally know the author but he is very helpful and his book is very insightful and aimed towards those who never programmed before.

Also Sitepoint.com has a nice set of articles and a book out about using C# .NET and ASP to make a website. That would be a fun way to start.

Answer (score 0):

Start by downloading the IDE for C#... [Visual Studio Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/). Free and no strings attached.

On that page, you can find learning resources as well. MSDN Express provide a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a copy of Juval Lowy's Programming .NET Components. I'm still picking stuff from that one.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I feel as if I was new myself. There are always things to learn and discover.

Get a book, read first 2-3 chapters, then start to code reading in parallel the rest of the book. Think of a little project or a toy to program - and go for it!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the trick explained.

http://norvig.com/21-days.html

As with any other programming language, its not about how to start coding, its about what to code, how to study it, and to code! Being involved in a OS project always helps, so you can learn from the success or mistakes others developers make.

Hope it serves, Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Simply: don't start programming C#. 
Try a real language like Java, C++ or Lisp.

Java is a classic beginner language.
And if you already knew it, you would not be asking that one-liner questions on stackoverflow.